# Normal // Association // Dataset workaround for some user query operators

Tags: dataset, associations

Given example tabular data (ie, with rows and columns, or "data frames")

```
data = Table[<| "key1" -> i, "key2" -> i + 10 , 
   "key3" -> i + 20|>, {i, 4}] //Dataset
```

[image]

The following query operator almost works to associate (the values of) a selected "primary" key at first level:

```
primaryKey[key_] := Sequence[All, Slot[key] -> KeyDrop[#, key] &]
```

This allows the lookup syntax:

```
data[primaryKey["key1"]][3]

(* 3 -> <|"key2" -> 13, "key3" -> 23|> *)
```

How to modify this query to handle:

1. Return only the value `<|"key2" -> 13, "key3" -> 23|>`, similar to how `data[All, #key1 &] // Normal` returns only the values `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.
2. Dataset doesn't recognize the implicit global association structure, flattening the data by 1 level:

   data[primaryKey["key1"]]

[image]

The following workaround works but how to incorporate in the operator?

```
data[primaryKey["key1"]] // Normal // Association // Dataset
```

[image]

The same issue arises from other restructuring operators, like generating an association from (the values of) two specified keys eg

```
data[All, #key1 -> #key3 &][2]

(* 2 -> 22 *)
```

Whereas

```
data[All, #key1 -> #key3 &] // Normal // Association // 
  Dataset // #[2] &

(* 22 *)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the descending operator `All` to the ascending `Association` seems to work at turning the resulting list of rules into an association.

```
primaryKey[key_] := Sequence[Association, Slot[key] -> KeyDrop[#, key] &]
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to @Leonid and @Rojo for answering the question.

I want to add that I'll be adding a specialized function to do precisely this operation (and its inverse).

I think it will be called Pivot (the existing, undocumented Pivot will go away), and it will work like this:

```
In[1]:= Pivot[{<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 3, b -> 4|>}, Key[a]]
Out[1]= <|1 -> <|b -> 2|>, 3 -> <|b -> 4|>|>

In[2]:= Pivot[<|1 -> <|b -> 2|>, 3 -> <|b -> 4|>|>, Key[a]] 
Out[2]= {<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|a -> 3, b -> 4|>}
```

Comment: +1 Nice. And the current undocumented `Pivot` will exist as some other function, `Transpose` will be extended, or it will just disappear?

Comment: @Rojo I don't know yet.

Comment: `Pivot` no longer works on V10.0.1.

Comment: @Murta Yes, Pivot is gone. Undocumented functions can be removed at the slightest whim, unfortunately :-). The truth is there is a much simpler and more useful operation that wants the name 'Pivot'.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon I can imagine.. to do something like Excel Pivot Table in Mathematica you have to create your own functions today. Pivot is one of the best Excel utilities, and MMA should have something similar if it really wants to make data science analysis easier.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I'd do this:

```
transformed = data[GroupBy[Key["key1"]], Delete[Key["key1"]] @* First]
```

This avoids the round-trip to a list of rules and back to `Association`.

Comment: Nice use of that peculiar descending operator `GroupBy`

Comment: @Rojo Thanks. Your method is also nice. Shows once again that Dataset is hackable, which is good.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thanks for the paradigm. This works also when  the key is duplicate, whereas Slot[key] returns only the last appearance.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, how does ascending composition by First work here? Substituting Last for First gives the same result.

Comment: @alancalvitti Basically, without `First`, you get a list of all results with this key, as a value for the key in a new assoc. `First` and `Last` give the same result only when the keys are unique, because then all groups will be lists with a single element.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, without First, data[GroupBy[Key@"key1"], Delete[Key@"key1"]] gives an error "Position specification Key[key1].. is not a machine-sized integer or a list..."

Comment: KeyDrop works in place of Delete.

Comment: @alancalvitti Of course. I meant the structure without the `Delete` part: `data[GroupBy[Key@"key1"]]`. When we apply `First`, it removes the list around the value, and then `Delete` removes they key. Just call `Normal` on intermediate results and play with it to see what's going on.

Comment: @alancalvitti My advice to you is to work out this example without Dataset, on the level of pure associations and lists, to see what's going on. This is certainly a much better way to see what's happening, than trial and error with various commands.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thanks, I'm testing with real data - and b/c of limitations of Dataset formatting it is certainly easier to display structure as nested lists and associations.

Comment: A different way to write the same thing could be `data[GroupBy[Key["key1"] -> KeyDrop["key1"]], First]`

Comment: @Rojo Good point.

Comment: This solution no longer works in V10.1 as `Key["key1"]` doesn't seem to be picked up?