# Combining key pivoting and lookup operators in Dataset

Tags: dataset, associations

This question is related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54843/normal-association-dataset-workaround-for-some-user-query-operators) re pivoting on keys.

Because of the nesting, using Leonid's method as starting point - single key:

```
pivotUp[key_] := Query[GroupBy[Key@key], KeyDrop[key]]
```

How to extend the operation iteratively - but partially - to create hierarhical Datasets from tabular data.

Interesting cases include duplicate values, which are pivoted to duplicate keys.

Consider:

```
pivotUp[keys_List] := 
 Sequence @@ (Flatten@{GroupBy[Key@#] & /@ keys, KeyDrop@keys})
```

Given:

```
data = AssociationThread[{"key1", "key2", "key3"} -> #] & /@  {{1, 
     "a", 10}, {1, "b", 20}, {2, "c", 30}} // Dataset
```

[image]

One way to use pivotUp is this:

```
  data[pivotUp[Key@"key1"]][All, pivotUp[Key@"key2"]]
```

This is more compact:

```
data[pivotUp[{"key1", "key2"}]]


  <|1 -> <|"a" -> {<|"key3" -> 10|>}, "b" -> {<|"key3" -> 20|>}|>, 
     2 -> <|"c" -> {<|"key3" -> 30|>}|>|> (* normal form *)
```

But how can "key3" be accessed, either with given pivotUp or alternatives? These don't work:

```
data[pivotUp[{"key1", "key2"}], "key3"]
```

[image]

The desired output is:

```
data[pivotUp[{"key1", "key2"}]][All, All, All, "key3"] // Normal

<|1 -> <|"a" -> {10}, "b" -> {20}|>, 2 -> <|"c" -> {30}|>|>
```

Ideally, these partial pivots should handle {__Association} structures.

Comment: But what't wrong with your last method (last line)? Why are you not satisfied by it?

Comment: We routinely deal with hierarhical data structures that can exceed this number of levels. It's too cumbersome to use the last method.

Comment: Your last eample gives me ``Failure[Dataset, {"MessageTemplate" :> Dataset::partatomic, 
  "MessageParameters" -> <|"Type" -> TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 
    "Part" -> "key3", "Symbol" -> Part|>}]``